# Can I match the corners WITHOUT expanding the path. Almost impossible, any creative cheeky way to do it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, pen-tool

Like adding extra anchor points, custom arrowheads etc...

I don't know how to google this problem.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly extend the line a little, and then use a black filled rectangle as an opacity mask.

Example

[image]

Or if you aren't worried about transparency (since white=non-printing anyway) a simple white filled rectangle to cover over the end would do the job as well.

Another alternative is to use a large rectangle around the whole stroke as a clipping path.